# react native not suggesting email with TextInput

Tags: react-native, email, autocomplete, textinput

React Native doesn't suggesting new user's commonly used email address on login form. LoginForm.js and Email.js is functional but it doesn't offer commonly used email addresses of the current user. I am not using firebase, google signing or facebook signing e.g. similar libraries so I need something built in feature of react native already has to make signing in, registering easier for my users.

LoginForm.js

```
....

<Email
    placeholder={i18n.t("i18n_email")}
    value={this.state.email}
    onChangeText={email => this.validate({ email })}
    autoCorrect={true}
    autoCapitalize="none"
    autoCompleteType="email"/>

....
```

On Email.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Text, TextInput, View, StyleSheet } from "react-native";

const styles = StyleSheet.create ({
  inputStyle: {
    zIndex: 1,
    position: 'absolute',

  },
  labelStyle: {
    fontSize: 18,
    paddingLeft: 20
  },
  containerStyle: {
    height: 50,
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
    width: '100%'
  }
});

const Email = ({
  value,
  onChangeText,
  placeholder,
  keyboardType,
  autoCompleteType,
  autoCapitalize
}) => {
  const { inputStyle, labelStyle, containerStyle } = styles;

  return (
    <View style={containerStyle}>
      <TextInput
        placeholder={placeholder}
        value={value}
        onChangeText={onChangeText}
        autoCapitalize={autoCapitalize}
        autoCompleteType={autoCompleteType}
        style={styles.inputStyle}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export { Email };
```

Answer (score 3):

I use this code. It works on both iOS and Android.

```
<TextInput
   testID="LoginEmailAddress"
   textContentType="emailAddress"
   keyboardType="email-address"
   style={commonStyles.textInput}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

for React Native `V0.72` you can use `inputMode = 'email'` to get email layout keyboard with `@` sign.

```
<TextInput
  inputMode="email"
  ...
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing the [textContentType](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#textcontenttype) prop on your `<TextInput>`.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I added  `textContentType='emailAddress'` unfortunately it doesn't affected. Besides my platform is Android.

Comment: I have added textContentType='emailAddress', but it not shows any difference. Now also the first lettern is in uppercase for the above. I am in iOS platform